# React-native cannot be launched in Android Studio, Error: Caused by: java.lang.Exception: /node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js

Tags: react-native, android-studio

Firstly, i'm a beginner first use react-native and android studio. There is the process i got stuck:

1. npx react-native init Demo
2. cd Demo and npm install
3. use android studio open Demo's android folder
4. android studio gave me an error

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 544 ms
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, -e, try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e) {console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);}]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, -e, try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e) {console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);}]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/dh/Documents/*Demos/react_native_demo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 413

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> /Users/dh/Documents/*Demos/react_native_demo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:119    cmd.option(opt.name, opt.description ?? '', opt.parse || (val => val), typeof opt.default === 'function' ? opt.default(rest[0]) : opt.default);                                          ^SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dh/Documents/*Demos/react_native_demo/node_modules/react-native/cli.js:13:11)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptTarget.addConfiguration(DefaultScriptTarget.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at 
       .
       .
       .
       .
       .
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: /Users/dh/Documents/*Demos/react_native_demo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:119    cmd.option(opt.name, opt.description ?? '', opt.parse || (val => val), typeof opt.default === 'function' ? opt.default(rest[0]) : opt.default);                                          ^SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dh/Documents/*Demos/react_native_demo/node_modules/react-native/cli.js:13:11)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.Instrumented$FileInputStreamConstructorCallSite.callConstructor(Instrumented.java:971)
    at ReactNativeModules.getCommandOutput(/Users/dh/Documents/*Demos/react_native_demo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle:413)
    at ReactNativeModules$getCommandOutput$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at ReactNativeModules.getReactNativeConfig(/Users/dh/Documents/*Demos/react_native_demo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle:441)
    at ReactNativeModules$getReactNativeConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at ReactNativeModules.<init>(/Users/dh/Documents/*Demos/react_native_demo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle:157)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at native_modules_624o5mk6x79p34lx2o10mf6q2.run(/Users/dh/Documents/*Demos/react_native_demo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle:511)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 193 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 3s
```

[image]

here is what i tried:

1. update @react-native-community/cli
2. swtich to yarn install

none of these solved the problem, i'm so confused about what's going on, please help

Comment: Have you ever figured out what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: I have this issue on mac, but when I tried it again on windows it worked fine. haayy